# How to build a regex to detect words not adjacent to or enclosed in braces

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

I am stuck in a problem with an application. I have following lines of text :

```
1) hi {my|your|his} name is {stacker|monster|overflow}
2) hi {my|your|his} job can be to {stacker|monster|overflow}
3) hi {my|your|his} car {stacker|monster|overflow}
```

**What I want :**

on the click of a button select and replace those words which do not have `{` or `}` just before or after the word i.e. in line 1 or 3 we do not have any such word. In line 2 we have "can" and "be".

I used substrings to check for { or } but it does not work. I thought there might be a regex to check for such words?

Thanks and happy new year. Quite sweet that you guys are helping on new year day :)

Comment: Define "word". As it is now, the words `your` and `monster` should match your definition.

Comment: sorry excluding the ones in {} also. Only the ones without any bracket and not adjacent to either { or }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<![{}]\s+|\{[^{}]*)\b\w+\b(?!\s+[{}]|[^{}]*\})
```

does this.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!        # Assert that we can't match this before the current position:
 [{}]\s*    # Any directly adjacent brace (plus optional whitespace)
|           # or
 \{[^{}]*   # an opening brace before any other brace.
)
\b\w+\b     # Match an entire word
(?!         # Assert that we can't match this after the current position:
 \s*[{}]    # Any directly adjacent brace (plus optional whitespace)
|           # or
 [^{}]*\}   # a closing brace before any other brace.
)
```

Caveat: This fails if braces can be nested.

Comment: Problem: `(?<![{}]\s+|\{[^{}]*)` is an arbitrary length lookbehind, only the .NET regex languages support that

Comment: @fge i want for vb.net only :)